# is any windows application available for accelerometer based computer mouse

Tags: accelerometer

I want to make an AIR mouse using Arduino and accelerometer, for this i used USB to TTL converter i have done everything successfully but can anyone tell me how use it in computer. I mean i don't know how to make computer application for this mouse. please suggest me any application for this. And give any idea for "how can i use Bluetooth for this."

Comment: yeah, except that question is from the same user and now shares the same title (it did not earlier). Something wacky going on with the SO database or the migration, or it is just acting weird in general. Maybe EE migrated, the user re-posted, then they migrated it again?

Answer (score 1):

try "remotemouse.exe"
its a open source application you can modify the codes according to your requirement